# Android Estudio página de inicio diferente cada día

Tags: android-studio

Quiero hacer una aplicación en la que al ingresar aparezca la pantalla que contenga la información editada por mi, que corresponde a la fecha del dispositivo.
Mañana aparecerá la pantalla con la información de mañana, etc.
Además por menú ingreso a una pantalla con el calendario vigente del dispositivo que servirá como menú para ir a pantallas de días pasados y futuros.

Quiero saber dónde consigo el código para adaptar mi idea.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, para realizar tu idea no necesitas programar en la app lo que vas a querer por dia ( si no es siempre igual ) para realizar lo que buscas te recomiendo usar un backend como firebase de google o json parse , con json parse se hace mas facil ya que creas el archivo json , lo subes a la web y de ahi lo editas y se editan los elementos de tu app sin tener que actualizarla, por que si programas todos los dias lo que quieres en tu app vas a tener que compilarla y subirla todos los dias , lo que generaria muchas molestias al usuario de tener que actualizar la app diariamente.

Te adjunto este tutorial de json , el mejor que encontre http://thebestandroide.blogspot.com.ar/2014/11/crear-y-leer-json-desde-android.html?m=1